# Why is this JavaScript regular expression not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, alpha

For some reason this is not working, yet all my searches say it should work.

I have an id on an element where I am trying to increment the value by 1.

so let's say I have

```
<input id="someText1">
```

I want to change the 1 to a 2, so I end up with

```
<input id="someText2">
```

I've tried to match just the text using

```
text = $("input").attr("id").match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/);
```

But when I output the value of text, I get null

Please help!

Comment: I fear the situation that makes you feel that you have to do this.  Can you post your ultimate goal so that I can perhaps offer up a different approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `$` sign (the text does end with a number and you're telling it that it ends with a letter)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression should be

```
text = $("input").attr("id").match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/);
```

Are you after this?

```
var text = $("input").attr("id").replace(/[0-9]+$/, "");
var num = $("input").attr("id").replace(/^[a-zA-Z]+/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `match` selector must equal the ID exactly, and as your regex matches any string containing ONLY a-z and A-Z, it doesn't match `someText1`! You should try

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a class name selector, such as `$('.inputs')` as it will be faster than getting all the input elements on the page and then filtering by id (esp. in modern browsers).